# Is either 霊験 or あらたか used outside the phrase 霊験あらたか?

Tags: words, set-phrases, collocations

Is either 霊験【れいげん】 or あらたか used outside of the phrase 霊験【れいげん】あらたか "miraculous"? (I believe れいけん is also a possible reading of 霊験?)

[The goo辞書 entry for あらたか](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/7208/m0u/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B/) has 「霊験―な神」 as its example phrase, and [the entry for 霊験](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/234123/m0u/%E9%9C%8A%E9%A8%93/) has 「―あらたか」. I'm also not seeing much else for either word alone on Google besides companies named あらたか and proper-noun looking things like books named 霊験記.

(I know this isn't a terribly interesting question; it's just that I have 霊験あらたか on a flashcard for some reason and I'm wondering whether I should learn it as two separate words or as one indecomposable phrase.)

Comment: Click around on some of the patterns here: http://corpus.tsukuba.ac.jp/headword/N.17428/#tabfreqorder

Comment: And here, too. http://corpus.tsukuba.ac.jp/headword/AN.01402/#tabfreqorder

Answer (score 1):

Daring to answer this without looking at anything...

Basically I recognize this 霊験あらたか as a set phrase. I can hardly expect あらたか used, except directly after 霊験. I feel I hear れいけん more often than れいげん, but I believe both readings are okay.

霊験 is uncommon, and I'm not very sure about how to use 霊験 combined with other words. If I saw something like "霊験を感じる", "富士山の霊験", or "霊験溢れる森", I would feel that's not so unnatural. but I can't say this is "correct" or not unless I google.

Answer (score 1):

「霊験のある」and「効験あらたか」came up to my mind.

However, I think these expressions are not so common.